# How to display a modal message box in selenium

Tags: java, browser, selenium

I have written some browser automation tests using selenium and the java binding (using eclipse).

The customer wants to have a message box saying "Test xy is starting" 
and wants the tester to confirm the start, i.e. a modal message box.

Can this be achieved somehow?

I have still not found a good reference to selenium (google code is quite good,
but it seems to miss some parts).

Tried already to a JDialog with a Webdriver.wait, but it did not work.
Either it does not wait at all or it waits forever.

Comment: I think, you can use Swings package in java to create different message boxes, user input box and many other GUI based elements. you can try checking functtions inside the JOptionPane component in Swings.

Comment: Good idea, works as a drop-in, but is not modal to the browser window. sometimes the window is even in the background of the browser. Perhaps something can be done about that.

Comment: Why wouldn't `((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("alert('Test xy is starting');");` work? That should throw up a JavaScript alert in the browser being automated, and if memory serves, should block until the alert is dismissed.

Comment: Thank you! Will try it out as soon as I can get a grab on my machine.

Comment: @JimEvans Actually it should be  `((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("alert('Test xy is starting');");`

Comment: @user1413 Sorry, but no. You've conflated the .NET API (where the interface is named `IJavaScriptExecutor` and the method is named `ExecuteScript`, note the "I" in the interface name, and the PascalCase method name), and the Java API (no "I" in the interface name, and the method is camelCased).

Comment: @JimEvans Alright. Thank you for telling me